# No active members in the cluster group in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, cluster-computing

I am doing a simple cluster configuration in two diff machines tomcat servers.
Each time i am starting the tomcat i am getting an error like no active members in cluster group.
i am attaching the cluster configuration

```
<Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" channelSendOptions="8">
    <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager"
        expireSessionsOnShutdown="false" sendAllSessions="true"
        notifyListenersOnReplication="true"/>
    <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
        <Membership className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.McastService"
            address="111.222.222"
            port="64222"
            frequency="500"
        dropTime="3000"/>
        <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
            address="auto"
            port="6000"
            autoBind="100"
            selectorTimeout="5000"
        maxThreads="6"/>
        <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
            <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender" timeout="30000"/>
        </Sender>
        <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
            <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.MessageDispatch15Interceptor"/>
            <!-- <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.ThroughputInterceptor"/>-->
    </Channel>
    <!--<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve"
        filter=".*\.gif;.*\.js;.*\.jpg;.*\.png;.*\.
        htm;.*\.html;.*\.css;.*\.txt;"/> -->
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" filter=".*\.gif;.*\.js;.*\.jpg;.*\.png;.*\.
        htm;.*\.html;.*\.css;.*\.txt;" /> 
    <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve"/>
    <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
     <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
</Cluster>
```

Please do suggest if i am mising some configurations.
Thanks in advance for any suggestion
Bibhu

Answer (score 0):

The address of the tribes group does not look good: address="111.222.222" port="64222". Thats neither a valid IPv4 nor a valid port (>64k). Use something like this; what you can find in the [manual](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/cluster-howto.html):

```
address="228.0.0.4"
port="45564"
```